# Enum-based static array: C header

Tags: c

I have an enumeration of values in a C header file.  I want to define an additional array or group of values, where each value corresponds to one of the enumeration values.  Essentially, the array would be a lookup table for some information pertinent to each enumerated value.  However, I want to do this at compile time in a header file.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Here is an example of how to accomplish it using two separate enumerations or definition structs.  Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this using only the op enums?

```
enum op {
op1,
op2,
op3
};

enum op_information {
op1_info = 0xff,
op2_info = 0xf3,
op3_info = 0xc1
}
```

UPDATE:  An equally valuable help to me would answering if there is any way to statically define an array using references.  That is, instead of doing:

```
ushort op_information = { 0xff, 0xf3, 0xc1 },
```

can we accomplish

```
ushort op_information[3]
op_information[op.op1] = 0xff;
op_information[op.op2] = 0xf3;
op_information[op.op3] = 0xc1
```

at compile time?

Answer (score 7):

Using C99 *designated initializers*:

```
ushort op_information[] = {
    [op1] = 0xff,
    [op2] = 0xf3,
    [op3] = 0xc1,
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, it looks like this feature is no longer supported in C++?  This header file will unfortunately be used in C, C++, and C# applications.

Comment: @TSM: You will share a C header file *with C# applications*?

Comment: @TSM: Designated initializers are not in C++ at all (they were only added to C, and C and C++ are separate languages with separate standards). You can work around that by defining these constants in a C file linked into all your projects (e.g. as a library). Your header then only needs to say `extern ushort op_information[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old GNU cpp tricks.  Create an include file that's entirely composed of macro calls.

```
/* opdefs.h */
OP(op1, 0xff)
OP(op2, 0xff)
```

Now build the necessary enums by repeatedly defining and undefining OP with an include between:

```
#define OP(Id, Val) Id,
enum op {
#include "opdefs.h"
};
#undef OP

// Handy for debugging, e.g. printf("%s", op_to_string[the_op]);
#define OP(Id, VaL) #I,
char op_to_string[] = {
#include "opdefs.h"
};
#undef OP

#define OP(Id, Val) Id ## _info = Val,
enum op_information {
#include "opdefs.h"
};
#undef OP
```

I'm sure you see that the same include will also allow you to generate the array you seek.

**Addition**

As @Sebastian suggested, you can replace the include file with another macro:

```
#define OP_DEFS \
OP(op1, 0xff) \
OP(op2, 0xff)

#define OP(Id, Val) Id,
enum op { OP_DEFS };
#undef OP

#define OP(Id, VaL) #I,
char op_to_string[] = { OP_DEFS };
#undef OP

#define OP(Id, Val) Id ## _info = Val,
enum op_information { OP_DEFS };
#undef OP
```

Generally the include file method is cleaner if there are many OP defs or if you need to use them from several sources.  The macro method is cleaner for short lists in one file only.

Comment: You don't need the include file. #define OPDEFS(OP) OP(op1, 0xff) OP(op2, 0xff) works, too (you can split it onto separate lines with backslashes).

Comment: @Sebastian Sure enough.  I've always had long lists of definitions so found the include to be cleaner, but your method is better for short lists.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result to be a compile time constant, you could just do a nested ternary expression

```
#define INFO(X) ( (X) == op1 ? val1 : ((X) == op2 ? val2 : .... ) )
```

beware that this evaluates `X` several times, so if `X` has side effects you are screwed.

But if `X` is a compile time integer expression any C compiler *must* evaluate this a compile time, also.

With the new C standard, C11, `_Generic` feature there are even ways to figure out if that is a compile time expression, and, if it isn't, to replace the ternary expression by a function call that avoids the evaluation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you might want to have a self-test.  Use asserts for the self-test so you only do the test in a debug build.

```
enum op {
    op1,
    op2,
    op3,
};

enum op_information {
    op1_info = 0xff,
    op2_info = 0xf3,
    op3_info = 0xc1,
};

ushort op_information = { op1_info, op2_info, op3_info };

// then somewhere, e.g. in a function called _OnBootup():
assert(op1_info == op_information[op1]);
assert(op2_info == op_information[op2]);
assert(op3_info == op_information[op3]);
```

Also, for really boring and really data-driven stuff like the above, I will usually write a Python program that writes the appropriate C code.  You don't really need to do it for really fixed things, like when you are writing a decoder for a frozen standard codec; but if the enums and matching values are in flux (as during R&D) and it might be error-prone to keep everything up to date, just put the op names and the values in a Python dictionary and have Python code generate all the boilerplate C code.  (And obviously while I use Python, you should use whatever you prefer.)